# How can get output of command like this to a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, output

how can get output of this command to a variable.

```
wevtutil qe system "/q:*[System [(EventID=1074)]]" /rd:true /f:text /c:1 | findstr /i "date"
```

my solution dose not working

```
FOR /F %i IN ('wevtutil qe system "/q:*[System [(EventID=1074)]]" /rd:true /f:text /c:1 | findstr /i "date"') DO set VARIABLE=%i
echo %VARIABLE%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "escape" the `|` to tell the parser that it's part of the inner command (`for ... in ('command') ...`). Without escaping, it ends the `for`command too early, leading to a script-breaking error.

Also in batchfiles, you have to double the `%` for the metavariables.

Third, `for` gets the first token ("word") only without specification which token(s) to use and which delimiters to use to separate them.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wevtutil qe system "/q:*[System [(EventID=1074)]]" /rd:true /f:text /c:1 ^| findstr /i "date"') DO set VARIABLE=%%i
echo %VARIABLE%
```

To get the date only, use `"tokens=2"` instead of `"delims="` (to take the second token ("word"), using standard delimiters space, tab, comma)

Answer (score 0):

operators need to be escaped in paranthesis. | becomes (^|), also ( ^& ^> ^^ )

Comment: cant get it, please  explain more